# Redistributing the .NET framework and SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql, .net, installation, redistributable

I have an app written in C#. It's a commercial app, written using nothing but free software (Visual C# express and SQL express). So, so far it's all clean.

For the app to work, both the .NET framework and SQL Server Express need to be installed on the clients computer. I already know some of the clients don't have internet connection (for security reasons), so I need to make an installer that would locally (off line) install all the dependencies (.NET framework and SQL Server Express).

So, can I (legally) burn both the .NET framework and SQL Server Express installers on the instalation CD so that the client can just click install and not have to worry about anyting?

I tried contacting Microsoft directly to ask them, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [this](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-redistribute.aspx) Microsoft page will tell you what you needd to redistribute SQL Server Express. And [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994395.aspx) a link about redistributing the .NET framework.

Basically, you don't really have any major restrictions when it comes to redistributing either of them. Just dig around the Microsoft website and you'll find everything you'd ever need.

Comment: That .NET FX redist page is for .NET 1.0. For 3.5 there are pages [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xak0tsbd%28VS.90%29.aspx). The 4.0 page doesn't seem to have been update for RTM, but a [search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=Redistributing%20the%20.NET%20Framework&ac=8) gives plenty of candidate pages.

Comment: @Richard thanks for the links. I doubt there have been significant changes from 3.5 to 4, though.